# Union type with incompatible signatures

Tags: typescript, types

I'm the author of the [WEBMIDI.js library](https://webmidijs.org/). I'm trying to add TypeScript support and it is proving challenging. The latest problem is that I'm getting this error:

```
TS2349: This expression is not callable.
Each member of the union type '(<T extends keyof InputEventMap>(type?: Symbol | T, listener?: InputEventMap[T], options?: { channels?: number | number[]; context?: any; remaining?: number; }) => void) | (<T extends keyof OutputEventMap>(type?: Symbol | T, listener?: OutputEventMap[T], options?: { ...; }) => void)' has signatures, but none of those signatures are compatible with each other.
```

Not being a TypesScript user, I'm not sure what's going on.

Here's an example of the code that triggers the problem:

```
WebMidi.addListener("disconnected", e => {
    e.port.removeListener();
})
```

Here are what I think are the relevant sections of the TypeScript declaration file (which can also be viewed in full [here](https://github.com/djipco/webmidi/blob/master/typescript/webmidi.d.ts)):

```
export interface Event {
  target: Input | InputChannel | Output | WebMidi;
  timestamp: DOMHighResTimeStamp;
  type: string;
}

export interface PortEvent extends Event {
  port: Input | Output;
}

export class Input extends EventEmitter {

  addListener<T extends keyof InputEventMap>(
    e: Symbol | T,
    listener: InputEventMap[T],
    options?: {
      "arguments"?: any[];
      "channels"?: number | number[];
      "context"?: any;
      "duration"?: number;
      "prepend"?: boolean;
      "remaining"?: number;
    }
  ): Listener | Listener[];

  /* lots more stuff here */

}

export class Output extends EventEmitter {

  addListener<T extends keyof OutputEventMap>(
    e: Symbol | T,
    listener: OutputEventMap[T],
    options?: {
      "arguments"?: any[];
      "context"?: any;
      "duration"?: number;
      "prepend"?: boolean;
      "remaining"?: number;
    }
  ): Listener | Listener[];

  /** lots more stuff here **/

}
```

Would a kind soul help me fix this problem for my TypeScript user?

Comment: Hi! The way SO works, your whole question (including any necessary code) has to be **in** your question, not just linked. Three reasons: People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; some sites are blocked for some users; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future. Please put the necessary type information **in** the question.

Comment: Okay, I will try and do that. However, the TypeScript definitions are quite long and I'm not even sure where the problem lies...

Comment: Ideally you'd provide a [mre] suitable for pasting into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/w661yw) or, barring that, a link to a properly configured web IDE project, where the issue is clearly demonstrated.  Otherwise the bar to entry for someone who wants to spend their free time helping might be too high to be realistic.

Comment: I added a live example demonstrating the problem in the TypeScript playground: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?declaration=false&target=99#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbwOoFMBGBZYATYBfOAMyghDgCIB3dEHYcgbgCgnVM6A6FAOwEM0ANigAUASg4wAFj2Fi4AXgB8iFnDhssuDr2zYAMsADOMHiijDyuQwGMI3bimsns5ADRwUC5QiZq1KDkhYDigUEAgANxQDY1NzUWY1PASWZOYgA

Comment: I reworded and simplified the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71175379/typescript-union-type-with-incompatible-signatures-2nd-try

Comment: Note that unless you "@jcalz" me, I won't necessarily be notified of comments (don't ask me why, I didn't write Stack Overflow).  The playground link above does not seem to demonstrate anything (there's no error, for example).

Comment: Since you opened a new question would you like to delete this one?