# TypeScript union type with incompatible signatures (2nd try)

Tags: typescript

I want to provide TypeScript support for my WEBMIDI.js library. This library has a `WebMidi` object which triggers various events. For example, you can use `addEventListener()` to listen for the `disconnected` event on the `WebMidi` object:

```
WebMidi.addEventListener("disconnected", e => {
    e.port.removeListener();
});
```

As you can see above, when the event is dispatched, the library calls the specified callback function passing it a `PortEvent`. The `PortEvent` object contains a `port` property which is either an `Input` or an `Output` object.

I thought I could use this type definition for the `PortEvent`:

```
export interface PortEvent extends Event {
    port: Input | Output;
}
```

However, the TypeScript compiler is not happy since the `removeListener()` method does not have exactly the same signature in both `Input` and `Output` objects.

How can I resolve this?

Thank you.

P.S. This is a simplified and reworded version of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70928770/union-type-with-incompatible-signatures?noredirect=1#comment125389241_70928770).

Comment: Make signatures identical? Ideally you should inherit your port, input and output classes from same base class, which declares (abstract) removelistener method.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/NlgdXw) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: The difference in signature is minimal. Basically, the `removeListener()` method of both `Input` and `Output` objects accepts different event names. However, I cannot pretend that events triggered by `Input` are also triggered by `Output` when it's not the case...